# R - Why does my function appear to work but not update tibbles within a list?

Tags: r, list, function, global, tibble

I have a list of tibbles and use the code below
I expect that each tibble in the list will have a column added with a factor (one of 16 levels).  I can see exactly what I want being printed to the console, but in the global environment, my list of tibbles remains the same.  What am I doing wrong?

```
fn <- function(df){
  df$col1 = cut(df$col1, 16)
  return(df)
  
for (df in listoftibbles){
    df <- fn(df)
    print (df)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `for` loop, it is not updating the element in `listoftibbles` i.e.. if we want to do this, loop over the sequence of the object and update by assignment

```
for(ind in seq_along(listoftibbles)) {
    listoftibbles[[ind]] <- fn(listoftibbles[[ind]])
}
```

The `for` loop in `R` is a for each loop which returns the values of the `list` element.  The 'df' object is a temporary object created on the fly.  This can be checked via `ls` (suppose there are 2 list elements)

```
> ls(pattern = '^df$')
character(0) # no object 
> for(df in listoftibbles) print(ls(pattern = '^df$'))
[1] "df"
[1] "df"

> ls(pattern = '^df$')
[1] "df" # now there is an object
```

The value of the object 'df' will be the last `tibble` of `listoftibbles`

and the address can be checked as well

```
> for(df in listoftibbles) print(tracemem(df))
[1] "<0x7fe59eb4f6c0>"
[1] "<0x7fe598361ac8>"
> tracemem(df) # last object created 
[1] "<0x7fe598361ac8>"
```

---

We can use `lapply` (First posted here)

```
listoftibbles <- lapply(listoftibbles, fn)
```

Or this doesn't need any function

```
listoftibbles <- lapply(listoftibbles, transform, col1 = cut(col1, 16))
```

or with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
listoftibbles <- map(listoftibbles, mutate, col1 = cut(col1, 16))
```

Comment: Thankyou for the code and the explanation (helpful). I used the listoftibbles <- lapply(listoftibbles, fn) option because the real function is much longer (cut is just the first line).

Answer (score 0):

Assign the output back to `listoftibbles`.

```
for (i in seq_along(listoftibbles)) {
  listoftibbles[[i]] <- fn(listoftibbles[[i]])
  print (listoftibbles[[i]])
}
```